# How to request react app over internet with express/node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a directory called `tree branch` with a `public` folder with my index.html and a `src` folder that has my js(app.js/index.js) and css(index.css, app.css) files. Inside the `tree branch` directory is a file called `server.js` here is the code

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Serve the js files and css from the React app
app.use('/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src/')));
app.use('/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src/')));

app.get('/', (req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));

});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port);

console.log('App is listening on port ' + port);
```

Here is the relevant code of `index.html`

```
  <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
   </body>
```

and `App.js`

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>
          Portfolio coming soon
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

here is `index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import '../css/index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The request for `index.html` seems to be working however it only render's an empty page without the generated content in `App.js`. How do I connect this code so when I request the `index.html` it renders the jsx elements?

Comment: Where did you write the `ReactDOM.render(<component/>, root)`?

Comment: You need to compile your React app to a build directory and serve the html file from that.

Comment: @Jai its in `index.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Development, you can run both server (React and Node) separately. For production, you will have to `build` your `react` app using

```
npm run build
```

and place that build in your `node.js` public folder. Now, you only need to run your `node.js` server in production and it will load the webpage with your `JSX`.

Comment: so I would have to build it before hosting it on my own domain?

Comment: @Jai, you are right. But he didn't attached the default `index.js` which mostly includes the `ReactDOM.render`

Comment: @securethebags Yes, you need to build it first. And then deploy on your server.

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan you mean run `node server.js` in production right? When I build the react app does that also need to happen on the server?

Comment: Right. Run `node server.js` in production. No nothing is required for build in production. What build does is it gives you the static HTML/CSS/JS files.

Comment: and do I have to place that in my node code? Ultimately do I still use `index.html` with `res.sendFile`?

Comment: You just only need to grab the `build` folder that react app creates and paste that content in your node.js project public folder. After that just run `node server.js` and have a look.